# Sort descending by salary where teacher year = 3

Tags: c#

I have a list of teachers and I want to sort in descending order by salary teachers who have years of work experience = 3.

I want experience != 3 to keep their index (keep their position) and only sorting by salary teacher have experience = 3

Please help me to solve this problem.

```
class Teacher
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public double salary { get; set; }

    public Teacher()
    {
    }

    public Teacher(int id, string name, int year, double salary)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

```
List<Teacher> teacher = new List<Teacher>();
teacher.Add(new Teacher(1, "Teacher A", 4, 2000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(2, "Teacher B", 3, 3000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(3, "Teacher C", 5, 5000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(4, "Teacher D", 3, 4000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(5, "Teacher E", 3, 7000));
```

Output:

```
1, Teacher A, 4, 2000
5, Teacher E, 3, 7000
3, Teacher C, 5, 5000
4, Teacher D, 3, 4000
2, Teacher B, 3, 3000
```

Comment: The output you shared seems to include all the teachers, not only those with three years of experience. Can you clarify the requirement?

Comment: didn't you already _ask_ this question previously? with exactly as much information as you provided in this question? it has been closed for a reason, you know. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You should be able to solve this easily by asking a search engine how to filter / sort list in c#. When you tried, please share what you've tried and what's not working.

Comment: So you want experience != 3 to keep thier index and only experience = 3 to move?

Comment: Unrelated: `double salary` - avoid using floating point numbers for money.

Comment: @magnus yes, that's what i want

Comment: You should update your question with that information

Comment: Please follow proper naming conventions for naming properties of the class , they should be PascalCase notation

Comment: Please upvote my answer if you find it useful

Comment: Ugly but working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bIedWe

Comment: @fildor can you explain it for me, i don't undertand but your solution is true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugly Solution, but working:

Mind: Conversion to Array is not neccessary.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Teacher> teacher = new List<Teacher>();
teacher.Add(new Teacher(1, "Teacher A", 4, 2000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(2, "Teacher B", 3, 3000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(3, "Teacher C", 5, 5000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(4, "Teacher D", 3, 4000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(5, "Teacher E", 3, 7000));
        
        var teachArr = teacher.ToArray();

        // Create separate List of only those teacher, you want to re-order
        // So, filter and sort.
        var threeYearTeachArr = teacher
                                  .Where(t => t.year == 3)           // Filter
                                  .OrderByDescending(t => t.salary)  // Sort
                                  .ToArray();                        // Do it!
        
        // Then replace all filtered items in the original collection
        // with the sorted ones. => Only filtered will change places.
        // We traverse 2 arrays, so we create two indexes and check both against their
        // respective collection sizes, but we increment only the "original"
        for( int i = 0, threes = 0; i < teachArr.Length && threes < threeYearTeachArr.Length; i++ )
        {
            // only if the current entry is one of those we sorted...
            if( teachArr[i].year == 3 ) 
            {
                // ... replace it with the next entry in the sorted list.
                // post-increment: use threes' value, then increment
                teachArr[i] = threeYearTeachArr[threes++]; 
            }
        }
                
        foreach( var t in teachArr )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{t.id} {t.name} | {t.year} | {t.salary}");
        }
    }
}

class Teacher
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public double salary { get; set; }

        public Teacher()
        {
        }

        public Teacher(int id, string name, int year, double salary)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.year = year;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
}
```

Output:

```
1 Teacher A | 4 | 2000
5 Teacher E | 3 | 7000
3 Teacher C | 5 | 5000
4 Teacher D | 3 | 4000
2 Teacher B | 3 | 3000
```

See in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AaIqzE

Comment: Mind: Conversion to Array is probably unneccessary.

Comment: Your solution is true but I don't understand, can you explain it

Comment: I added comments to explain. If you have questions, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

A simple **and *naive*** solution would be to just do a simple bubble sort where you only consider the year 3 teachers:

```
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < teacher.Count; i1++)
{
    if (teacher[i1].year != 3)
        continue;

    for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < teacher.Count; i2++)
    {
        if (teacher[i2].year != 3)
            continue;
            
        if (teacher[i1].salary > teacher[i2].salary)
            (teacher[i1], teacher[i2]) = (teacher[i2], teacher[i1]);
    }
}
```

This will have a performance characteristic of `O(n^2)` so it will perform badly if you have a lot of teachers. Fildor has a better solution, I'm just presenting an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting puzzle.

My first thought is to pair the list with their indices, then split the list into pass/fail based on your filter criteria: `teacher.year == 3`. Then we can order the pass list, fix up the indices separately, and finally re-merge the pass and fail data back together.

Wow, sounds complex. Let's try it and see how it looks:

```
List<Teacher> SortYear3(IEnumerable<Teacher> source)
{
    var indexed = source.Select((teacher, index) => (index, teacher)).ToArray();
    var pass = indexed.Where(pair => pair.teacher.year == 3);
    var passIndices = pass.Select(pair => pair.index).ToArray();
    var passOrdered = pass.Select(pair => pair.teacher).OrderByDescending(teacher => teacher.salary).ToArray();
    var reindex = Enumerable.Range(0, passIndices.Length).Select(i => (index: passIndices[i], teacher: passOrdered[i]));
    var merged = indexed.Where(pair => pair.teacher.year != 3).Concat(reindex).OrderBy(p => p.index);
    
    return merged.Select(pair => pair.teacher).ToList();
}
```

Well... it works, but mostly as an example of when LINQ is *not* the answer. And those intermediate arrays are a bit ugly, so let's not.

The next thought is to pull out the items you want to sort, sort them into an array, then feed them back in while adding items to a result list:

```
List<Teacher> SortYear3(List<Teacher> source)
{
    var sorted = source.Where(t => t.year == 3).OrderByDescending(t => t.salary).ToArray();
    var result = new List<Teacher>();
    for (int i = 0, sortindex = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        var next = source[i];
        if (next.year == 3)
            result.Add(sorted[sortindex++]);
        else
            result.Add(next);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Down to one array allocation, but it still looks a little clunky. Let's copy the list to start with and just replace the ones that we sorted:

```
List<Teacher> SortYear3(List<Teacher> source)
{
    var sorted = source.Where(t => t.year == 3).OrderByDescending(t => t.salary).ToArray();
    var result = source.ToList();
    for (int i = 0, sortindex = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
    {
        if (result[i].year == 3)
            result[i] = sorted[sortindex++];
    }
    return result;
}
```

That looks much better... and is now almost exactly what @fildor wrote. Well, that's embarrassing. Let's spice it up a little: make it generic, give it some parameters to specify the filtering and sorting, etc.

```
IEnumerable<T> SortSelected<T, TKey>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter, Func<T, TKey> sortKey, bool descending = true)
{
    var result = source.ToList();
    var filtered = result.Where(filter);
    var sorted = (descending ? filtered.OrderByDescending(sortKey) : filtered.OrderBy(sortKey)).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < sorted.Count; i++)
    {
        if (filter(result[i]))
            result[i] = sorted[j++];
    }
    return result;
}

List<Teacher> SortYear3(List<Teacher> source)
    => SortSelected(source, t => t.year == 3, t => t.salary, true).ToList();
```

(OK, so maybe I shouldn't answer these things when I've been up for more than 24 hours.)

Comment: really amazed because your answer is quite long and thoughtful. But I will refuse to understand, hahaha

Comment: _"and is now almost exactly what @fildor wrote. Well, that's embarrassing."_ - Erm ... "thank you"??

Comment: Mind, that in my solution, I stop iterating when there no more sorted items. May be useless, may spare you 100s of iterations ...

Comment: @Fildor That wasn't intended to be negative, just that it would be redundant to post a second answer with the same solution :)

Comment: Did not take offense :D Just sounded funny.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this answer, it is much more easier to understand and more optimised

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
List<Teacher> teacher = new List<Teacher>();
teacher.Add(new Teacher(1, "Teacher A", 4, 2000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(2, "Teacher B", 3, 3000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(3, "Teacher C", 5, 5000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(4, "Teacher D", 3, 4000));
teacher.Add(new Teacher(5, "Teacher E", 3, 7000));
    
var expTeacher=teacher.Where(x=>x.year==3).OrderByDescending(x=>x.salary).ToList();

    for(int i=0,j=0;i<teacher.Count && j<expTeacher.Count;i++)
    {
        if(teacher[i].year==3)
        {
            teacher[i]= expTeacher[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    foreach(var teach in teacher)
    {
        
    Console.WriteLine(teach.id+", "+teach.name+", "+teach.year+", "+teach.salary);
    }
    
    
    
   }
   }
   class Teacher
   {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public double salary { get; set; }

    public Teacher()
    {
    }

    public Teacher(int id, string name, int year, double salary)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing with the answer because in general you question is not clear either in requirement as the output which I assume is that what you are already getting.

According to response, at first what came to my head was

```
var t2 = teachers.Where(t => t.year == 3).OrderByDescending(t => t.salary);
var t3 = teachers.Where(t => !t2.Select(ts => ts.id).Contains(t.id));
var final = t2.Concat(t3);
```

Yes, it is not optimal an probably there is a better way to achieve that, but it gives output as needed (?)

```
Teacher = 5 Teacher E 3 7000
Teacher = 4 Teacher D 3 4000
Teacher = 2 Teacher B 3 3000
Teacher = 1 Teacher A 4 2000
Teacher = 3 Teacher C 5 5000
```

Comment: I want experience != 3 to keep thier index and only experience = 3 to move

Comment: @ĐứcLong move to what/where? What is index for you? order in array or your id?

Comment: @demo :( you can check output in question, it's same like you sort descending only odd number in array

Answer (score 0):

I understood and solved it by my way. Fildor give me the idea

```
 List<Coach> sorted = coaches.Where(x => x.YearOfExperience == 3).OrderByDescending(x => x.Salary).ToList();
            List<Coach> originalList = coaches;
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < originalList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (originalList[i].YearOfExperience == 3)
                {
                    originalList[i] = sorted[index++];
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in originalList)
            {
                item.show();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to filter your list for teachers having 3 years of experience then you can simply apply Where extension method using linq.

```
var requiredTeachers=teacher.Where(x=>x.year==3).OrderByDescending(x=>x.salary).ToList();
```

Comment: I use this method and my list is deleted all teachers without year = 3

Comment: So you want to move teachers with exp=3 up and rest of the teachers down in the list?

Comment: @ĐứcLong do you know how `Where` is working?

Comment: @Harkiratsingh Desired output is in the question.

Comment: @harkiratsingh I want experience != 3 to keep thier index and only experience = 3 to move